# Align Equations with the equals sign

Tags: equations, align

I am trying to align two equations, however they are not aligning at the equals sign but at the comma at the end of the equation. How can I change this?

```
\begin{align}



A_{ij}^y= 

\begin{cases} 

  1, & \text{if the link between $x_{i,j}$ and $y_{i,j}$ is included},\\ 

  0, & \text{otherwise},

\end{cases} \\

    R_{ij} = r_{ij},

\end{align}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please post full examples, not just fragments

Comment: you have not specified any alignment point. you need `&=`

Answer (score 5):

You have to place the alignment marks `&` at the equals sign:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
A_{ij}^y &=
\begin{cases*}
1, & if the link between $x_{i,j}$ and $y_{i,j}$ is included,\\
0, & otherwise,
\end{cases*}\\
R_{ij} &= r_{ij},
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Also, I have used the `cases*` environment from the `mathtools` package to  typeset the cases, as that typesets the second column in text mode.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You need `&` as alignment specifier, as in the cases environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
A_{ij}^y &= 
\begin{cases} 
  1, & \text{if the link between $x_{i,j}$ and $y_{i,j}$ is included},\\ 
  0, & \text{otherwise},
\end{cases} \\
    R_{ij} &= r_{ij},
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]